# Heroku problem : The page you were looking for doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have followed book until chapter 5 finished and it's working OK in my linux workstation
when I push to Heroku, all data pushed correctly but when I try to open Heroku (http://vivid-sky-685.heroku.com)

I get a 404 message.

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
>   You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

Below is my `Gemfile` for application

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem 'sqlite3'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.5.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc4'
end

gem 'rake','~> 0.8.7'
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

@odin here is my heroku logs , thanks

```
2011-09-11T10:41:57+00:00 heroku[router]: GET vivid-sky-685.heroku.com/y dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=728
2011-09-11T10:41:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-11T10:41:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-11T10:41:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/y" for 93.186.31.80 at 2011-09-11 03:41:57 -0700
2011-09-11T10:41:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-11T10:41:57+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/y"):
2011-09-11T10:41:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2011-09-11T10:41:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-11T10:41:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-11T10:41:57+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 93.186.31.80 - - [11/Sep/2011:03:41:57 -0700] "GET /y HTTP/1.1" 404 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9300; en) AppleWebKit/534.8+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.0.546 Mobile Safari/534.8+" vivid-sky-685.heroku.com
2011-09-11T11:45:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idl

2011-09-11T11:45:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2011-09-11T11:45:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to created
2011-09-11T11:45:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-11T11:45:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-09-11T11:45:30+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-09-11T11:45:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-11T11:45:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 16738 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-11T11:45:33+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-09-11T11:45:33+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-09-11T11:45:33+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:16738, CTRL+C to stop
2011-09-11T11:45:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-09-11T12:53:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2011-09-11T12:53:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2011-09-11T12:53:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-09-11T12:53:02+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-09-11T12:53:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-11T13:18:21+00:00 heroku[rake.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-11T13:18:23+00:00 app[rake.1]: Awaiting client
2011-09-11T13:18:23+00:00 app[rake.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`


2011-09-11T13:18:26+00:00 heroku[rake.1]: Process exited
2011-09-11T13:18:26+00:00 heroku[rake.1]: State changed from up to complete
2011-09-11T13:20:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2011-09-11T13:20:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to created
2011-09-11T13:20:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-11T13:20:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 48393 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-11T13:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-09-11T13:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-09-11T13:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:48393, CTRL+C to stop
2011-09-11T13:20:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-09-11T13:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-11T13:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-11T13:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 118.137.144.220 at 2011-09-11 06:20:07 -0700
2011-09-11T13:20:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-11T13:20:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant PagesController):
2011-09-11T13:20:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2011-09-11T13:20:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-11T13:20:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-11T13:20:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET vivid-sky-685.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=403ms status=404 bytes=728
2011-09-11T13:20:08+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 118.137.144.220 - - [11/Sep/2011:06:20:08 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0" vivid-sky-685.heroku.com
```

Comment: @widjajayd In your console type "heroku logs" and post the print-out you get.

Comment: Just so you know your not on your own, I'm suffering from this problem to. Did you ever find the cause?

Comment: I had this problem. I was working on a contact form on the route of contact-me which i had defined in routes.rb. When i visited the url supplied by heroku (e.g www.example_heroku_url.com/) i got the 404 like you. it was because i hadn't defined a root path or index view. so when i visited www.example_heroku_url.com/contact-me It worked. Really silly mistake but thought i'd share in case it helps someone

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the same problem; however, after changing 1 line code of production.rb located in `config/environments/production.rb` from

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

to

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

commit the new change. Then my sample app works fine on heroku

Comment: I had the same problem remaining even with assets compilation set as above. A deeper look at bundle log from heroku showed that the only warning was a suggestion to add gem rails_12factor. Surprisingly, it helps. This is rails 4.0.1 ruby 2.0.0, but still could help for someone?

Comment: For rails 4+ you need to include "gem 'rails_12factor' in your gemfile. Also need to be sure to use postgres for production instead of sqlite3:                                              group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end
gem 'rails_12factor'

Comment: Downvoting. You shouldn't be breaking asset precompilation in production; rather, you should be fixing the problem.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser well what's your better idea?

Comment: @barlop Heroku now runs `rake assets:precompile` as part of deployment. That part should just work.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser funnily enough I just ran into the error mentioned in the title now. I had no routes setup, and it wasn't going to the heroku welcome page(I guess 'cos I had done and pushed a commit to heroku). xji's solution of adding a route worked, which is fine as i'd want to be adding a route anyway. Locally i'd have got the rails welcome page from having no route.

Comment: @barlop Note that that has nothing to do with any of the assets stuff that I was talking about. (And the Rails welcome page is just public/index.html. If you go to an unrecognized URL locally, you get the development error page, which is different.)

Answer (score 30):

I know it's an old problem but I ran into it too. I realized I didn't change the root route in `config/routes.rb` before pushing. Not changing it might result in a welcome page locally, but on heroku it will get the above error.

Comment: Great answer, `rails server -e production` helped me narrow it down.

Comment: yeah having an empty routes.rb file(as in nothing within do and end) was an issue, which is strange since earlier today it wasn't an issue and went to the heroku welcome page, but doesn't matter as one wouldn't want an empty routes.rb anyway

Comment: yeah having an empty routes.rb file(as in nothing within do and end) was an issue. I guess i'd have got Rails welcome page locally.. And if i'd make no commit and not pushed any commit to Heroku, i'd get the Heroku welcome page.  But here i'd had no route and made a commit and pushed it to Heroku. So yeah, while i'd have got the local rails welcome page, I got that error from Heroku

Answer (score 7):

I'm using postgresql, and I also had page not showing up on heroku.

This command fixed it:

```
heroku run rake db:setup
```

and then

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

I had migrated before, but hadn't done the setup first.

I also had tried setting

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

in production.rb, but that made no difference.

Comment: Hm, maybe you should post your log output? See Hishalv's comment

Comment: Worked perfect for me!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried running in production mode locally? Try `rails server -e production` and see if you get the same error, which you can then debug. Also make sure you've done `heroku rake db:migrate`.

Comment: I did try server -e production and I still can see my site (although I lose css format),

Comment: I also did heroku rake db:migrate but the problem still exist , I upload my heroku logs above, thanks for your help

Comment: Try installing the "thin" web server (`gem 'thin'` in your Gemfile) and then do `bundle exec rails server thin -e production` and see what happens. That is the same server they use on Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a missing starting page that did not cause a problem in development mode but did cause the above issue on heroku. The accepted answer [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026492/heroku-rails-setup-the-page-you-were-looking-for-doesnt-exist) sheds more light.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this problem as well. Solved it by setting a root route. In my case, `root 'pages#home'` in config/routes.rb

If the root route is not set, you are redirected to localhost:3000. Hence,

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the
>   address or the page may have moved.

Comment: Just realized JI Xiang already provided this answer. Wish I had a time machine to beat him to the punch. :)

Answer (score 2):

**1. Always set a root in routes. That's rails 101**

I wouldn't go for making asset pre-compilation false all the time. For production app I feel it enhances the overall speed if assets have been pre-compiled.

**2. As a rule of thumb I always run `rake assets:precompile` before pushing to git. Please try it. and then commit to git repository and then heroku. Do `heroku restart`**

**3. Another cause could be heroku rake db:migrate, please check if you did it**

**4. Also this is my Gemfile setup for the development and production groups**

```
group :development do 
    gem 'sqlite3'        
end

group :production do    
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'heroku-deflater'   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similiar issue with heroku, found the answer from this question:

[RefineryCMS routes for Home page doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986301/refinerycms-routes-for-home-page-doesnt-work)

To save you reading, the solution was to update "Home" using Advanced Options, there is a question:

"Forward this page to another website or page"

Fill this in with a `/` and it should work. This sounds a little backwards, as its actually setting /my_page to redirect to "/". But the way to think of it is:

> Refinery pages extension is looking for a page with the url '/' to be
>   the home page. So by telling the page titled "Home" that you want it
>   to have the url '/' you're setting it as the definitive homepage as
>   far as Refinery pages extension is concerned. 
>   (quote from @Philip Arndt)

Answer (score 0):

So I had to run in this order and it worked for me

```
$ heroku rake db:migrate
$ heroku run rake db:setup
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify Ruby version in app
Rails 5 requires Ruby 2.2.0 or above. Heroku has a recent version of Ruby installed by default, however you can specify an exact version by using the ruby DSL in your Gemfile.

At the end of Gemfile add:

ruby "2.4.1"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the thing is that the app is missing the home like root. The default home page for Heroku is this HTML[the default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AG2Q.png). But if you try all your defined routes they will work like:

`appname.herokuapp.com/route`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but realized that I hadn't change the HTML verb from GET to ROOT in config/routes.rb file.

It was  `get "/hello", to: "application#hello"`

I updated it to `root "application#hello"`

I then pushed it to git and deployed it to production.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error because I pushed same non-master branch to heroku master using this command `git push heroku master` . Which obviously cause conflicts.

I also checked the routes using `heroku run rake routes`. But the output was not my actual routes. Not even single one.
The proper way to push your non-master branch to heroku master is

`git push -f heroku your_branch_name:master`