# Rails - The page you were looking for doesn't exist (after Heroku push)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, sqlite

I'm working through the http://ruby.railstutorial.org/. I am working on deploying my site, but I'm running into an error.

The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

Here is my current Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
     gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end
```

when I run

```
$ git push heroku master
```

I receive:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

My current

```
$ gem list

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-update (2.1.10)
sqlite3 (1.3.5)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

I am completely new to ruby and rails, so any help would be appreciated.

*** I've followed these instructions *** no success yet

```
$ gem install heroku
```

update Gemfile

```
gem 'heroku'

$bundle install
```

No luck.

here are my heroku logs:

```
...
2013-11-02T02:55:46.271237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=aqueous-hamlet-2818.herokuapp.com fwd="136.152.142.31" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=247ms status=404 bytes=1351
```

Comment: What does `$ heroku logs` show?

Comment: A lot of folks were helper by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376966/heroku-problem-the-page-you-were-looking-for-doesnt-exist?rq=1

Comment: @MichaelDurrant $ heroku logs -> returns /.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'heroku' (>= 0) among 13 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
gem install heroku
```

and then add heroku to your `Gemfile` and `bundle install`

More info on the gem at http://rubygems.org/gems/heroku

Comment: No luck, $ gem install heroku, then add to Gemfile "gem 'heroku' " then $bundle install -> $ git push heroku master and received "  Post-install message from heroku:
       !    The `heroku` gem has been deprecated and replaced with the Heroku Toolbelt.
"

Comment: Actually I think it did help.  That message is a deprecation warning, not an error.  Your stuff may be pushed ok.  check the web and then if no joy check logs again.  If you are still stuck, post a new question if this answered your initial question.

Comment: Also, make sure your keys are uploaded:  `heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`