# After an one night heroku delete links to my files in database. Can anyone explain what is that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, hyperlink

This is the link to the page with error
https://iitu.herokuapp.com/uploads/document/documentation/1/English_final.doc

Heroku logs looks like this, I used postgresql database and I pay for hobby version 7 dollars. But it still don't work.

```
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820194+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820195+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820196+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820197+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820199+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820200+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820201+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820203+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820205+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820206+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820208+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820223+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820224+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820225+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820226+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820227+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820228+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820229+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-12T13:02:03.820230+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-12T13:06:39.327754+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-12T13:06:42.730031+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
2015-09-12T13:06:43.407879+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-09-12T13:06:46.169246+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake aborted!
2015-09-12T13:06:46.170685+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2015-09-12T13:06:46.170753+00:00 app[worker.1]: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
2015-09-12T13:06:46.170359+00:00 app[worker.1]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
2015-09-12T13:06:47.285188+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2015-09-12T13:06:47.261841+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-09-12T13:09:13.653144+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=iitu.herokuapp.com request_id=ec4f7c0b-b5c8-4fa1-a60a-ba3217cd7479 fwd="182.118.35.12" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=418
2015-09-12T13:18:43.441935+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-12T13:18:48.988166+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
2015-09-12T13:18:49.574536+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-09-12T13:18:53.763054+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake aborted!
2015-09-12T13:18:53.763089+00:00 app[worker.1]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
2015-09-12T13:18:53.763409+00:00 app[worker.1]: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
2015-09-12T13:18:53.763407+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2015-09-12T13:18:54.631535+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-09-12T13:18:54.646378+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2015-09-12T13:24:30.736471+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/uploads/document/documentation/1/English_final.doc" for 5.76.235.35 at 2015-09-12 13:24:30 +0000
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738920+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738926+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738924+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/document/documentation/1/English_final.doc"):
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738927+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738929+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738930+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738931+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738933+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738934+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738936+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738938+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738939+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738940+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738941+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738943+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738944+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738945+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738946+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738947+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738948+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738950+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738951+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738952+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738953+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-12T13:24:30.738954+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-12T13:24:30.743000+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/uploads/document/documentation/1/English_final.doc" host=iitu.herokuapp.com request_id=d5af0e10-8852-4223-bc6a-013d05e73301 fwd="5.76.235.35" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=1829
2015-09-12T13:24:46.454078+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=iitu.herokuapp.com request_id=5e1ce582-1e5c-4989-be9e-78526ca01376 fwd="5.76.235.35" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=5946
2015-09-12T13:24:46.434036+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 5.76.235.35 at 2015-09-12 13:24:46 +0000
2015-09-12T13:24:46.444150+00:00 app[web.1]:   Document Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents"
2015-09-12T13:24:46.449511+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
2015-09-12T13:24:46.441428+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by DocumentsController#index as HTML
2015-09-12T13:24:46.448834+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered documents/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6.3ms)
2015-09-12T13:26:03.834225+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/uploads/document/documentation/1/English_final.doc" host=iitu.herokuapp.com request_id=c834d06b-3f0d-4d24-b710-5033c034fb50 fwd="81.139.61.190" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1829
2015-09-12T13:26:03.831585+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/uploads/document/documentation/1/English_final.doc" for 81.139.61.190 at 2015-09-12 13:26:03 +0000
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833624+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833630+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/document/documentation/1/English_final.doc"):
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833633+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833632+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833635+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833636+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833638+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833640+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833642+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833643+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833645+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833648+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833646+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833649+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833651+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833652+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833654+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833657+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833659+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833661+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833662+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833666+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833667+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-12T13:26:03.833668+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved. - is the text of error. Database is Heroku Postgres :: Database, dashboard shows hobby or I don't know how to check my account.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20916836/1413133) may be of help. Otherwise, please add the logs e.g. type `heroku logs`

Answer (score 4):

Heroku limits the way you can store data on their servers. To upload a file you need to use external service like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) .

Read this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3 to know more about