# My Heroku app is launching succesfully, but when I got to open it, I'm getting the error "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, aws-code-deploy

Here is my code...

Gemfile

```
: source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem 'rails',      '6.1.4.1'
gem 'puma',       '5.3.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '6.0.0'
gem 'webpacker',  '5.4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '5.2.1'
gem 'jbuilder',   '2.10.0'
gem 'bootsnap',   '1.7.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.4.2'
  gem 'byebug',  '11.1.3', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',        '4.1.0'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '2.3.1'
  gem 'listen',             '3.4.1'
  gem 'spring',             '2.1.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',           '3.35.3'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '3.142.7'
  gem 'webdrivers',         '4.6.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '1.2.3'
end
```

Application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def hello
    render html: "hello, world!"
  end
end
```

And development.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def hello
    render html: "hello, world!"
  end
end
```

I have been trying to get it an app launched for the last 24 hours that's bare bones, but I've been running into a ton of issues just getting it to properly deploy on Heroku. Now, it says "build succeed" and "deployed", but when I click on the link (https://fathomless-river-93030.herokuapp.com/), I am getting an error message.

I'm extremely new to Rails and Heroku, so any help is appreciated.

edit: here are my Heroku logs. The tutorial I'm currently using told me to 'ignore warning messages'. Not sure if that was good advice.

````
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
            Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.2.33
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.7.5
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.33
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching rake 13.0.6
       Installing rake 13.0.6
       Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
       Fetching minitest 5.15.0
       Fetching zeitwerk 2.5.4
       Fetching builder 3.2.4
       Installing minitest 5.15.0
       Installing zeitwerk 2.5.4
       Installing builder 3.2.4
       Fetching erubi 1.10.0
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
       Fetching racc 1.6.0
       Installing erubi 1.10.0
       Fetching crass 1.0.6
       Installing racc 1.6.0 with native extensions
       Fetching rack 2.2.3
       Installing crass 1.0.6
       Installing rack 2.2.3
       Fetching nio4r 2.5.8
       Installing nio4r 2.5.8 with native extensions
       Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.5
       Fetching marcel 1.0.2
       Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.5
       Installing marcel 1.0.2
       Fetching mini_mime 1.1.2
       Fetching msgpack 1.4.4
       Installing mini_mime 1.1.2
       Installing msgpack 1.4.4 with native extensions
       Using bundler 2.2.33
       Fetching ffi 1.15.5
       Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
       Fetching method_source 1.0.0
       Installing method_source 1.0.0
       Fetching pg 1.2.3
       Installing pg 1.2.3 with native extensions
       Fetching thor 1.2.1
       Installing thor 1.2.1
       Fetching tilt 2.0.10
       Installing tilt 2.0.10
       Fetching semantic_range 3.0.0
       Installing semantic_range 3.0.0
       Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
       Installing rack-test 1.1.0
       Fetching rack-proxy 0.7.2
       Installing rack-proxy 0.7.2
       Fetching i18n 1.9.1
       Installing i18n 1.9.1
       Fetching tzinfo 2.0.4
       Installing tzinfo 2.0.4
       Fetching sprockets 4.0.2
       Installing sprockets 4.0.2
       Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.5
       Installing websocket-driver 0.7.5 with native extensions
       Fetching mail 2.7.1
       Installing mail 2.7.1
       Fetching nokogiri 1.13.1 (x86_64-linux)
       Installing nokogiri 1.13.1 (x86_64-linux)
       Fetching puma 5.3.1
       Installing puma 5.3.1 with native extensions
       Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1
       Installing turbolinks 5.2.1
       Fetching activesupport 6.1.4.1
       Installing activesupport 6.1.4.1
       Fetching bootsnap 1.7.2
       Installing bootsnap 1.7.2 with native extensions
       Fetching loofah 2.13.0
       Installing loofah 2.13.0
       Fetching sassc 2.4.0
       Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native extensions
       Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Fetching globalid 1.0.0
       Installing globalid 1.0.0
       Fetching activemodel 6.1.4.1
       Installing activemodel 6.1.4.1
       Fetching jbuilder 2.10.0
       Installing jbuilder 2.10.0
       Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
       Fetching activejob 6.1.4.1
       Installing activejob 6.1.4.1
       Fetching activerecord 6.1.4.1
       Installing activerecord 6.1.4.1
       Fetching actionview 6.1.4.1
       Installing actionview 6.1.4.1
       Fetching actionpack 6.1.4.1
       Installing actionpack 6.1.4.1
       Fetching actioncable 6.1.4.1
       Installing actioncable 6.1.4.1
       Fetching activestorage 6.1.4.1
       Installing activestorage 6.1.4.1
       Fetching actionmailer 6.1.4.1
       Installing actionmailer 6.1.4.1
       Fetching railties 6.1.4.1
       Installing railties 6.1.4.1
       Fetching sprockets-rails 3.4.2
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.4.2
       Fetching actionmailbox 6.1.4.1
       Installing actionmailbox 6.1.4.1
       Fetching actiontext 6.1.4.1
       Installing actiontext 6.1.4.1
       Fetching webpacker 5.4.0
       Installing webpacker 5.4.0
       Fetching rails 6.1.4.1
       Installing rails 6.1.4.1
       Fetching sassc-rails 2.1.2
       Installing sassc-rails 2.1.2
       Fetching sass-rails 6.0.0
       Installing sass-rails 6.0.0
       Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 56 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
       Bundle completed (181.15s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v16.13.1-linux-x64
-----> Installing yarn-v1.22.17
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       yarn install v1.22.17
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 13.31s.
       I, [2022-02-02T15:32:31.755412 #1310]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a6b204d6/public/assets/manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js
       I, [2022-02-02T15:32:31.755678 #1310]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a6b204d6/public/assets/manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js.gz
       I, [2022-02-02T15:32:31.755839 #1310]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a6b204d6/public/assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
       I, [2022-02-02T15:32:31.755962 #1310]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a6b204d6/public/assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
       Compiling...
       Compiled all packs in /tmp/build_a6b204d6/public/packs
       Hash: 278be1bf80da8217ac88
       Version: webpack 4.46.0
       Time: 4069ms
       Built at: 02/02/2022 3:32:37 PM
                                               Asset       Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
              js/application-76cbbc8f0300eca44b41.js   69.4 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]  application
           js/application-76cbbc8f0300eca44b41.js.br   15.4 KiB          [emitted]              
           js/application-76cbbc8f0300eca44b41.js.gz   17.8 KiB          [emitted]              
          js/application-76cbbc8f0300eca44b41.js.map    205 KiB       0  [emitted] [dev]        application
       js/application-76cbbc8f0300eca44b41.js.map.br   43.8 KiB          [emitted]              
       js/application-76cbbc8f0300eca44b41.js.map.gz   50.8 KiB          [emitted]              
                                       manifest.json  364 bytes          [emitted]              
                                    manifest.json.br  127 bytes          [emitted]              
                                    manifest.json.gz  142 bytes          [emitted]              
       Entrypoint application = js/application-76cbbc8f0300eca44b41.js js/application-76cbbc8f0300eca44b41.js.map
       [0] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 552 bytes {0} [built]
       [4] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 480 bytes {0} [built]
       [5] ./app/javascript/channels/index.js 205 bytes {0} [built]
       [6] ./app/javascript/channels sync _channel\.js$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
           + 3 hidden modules
       
       Asset precompilation completed (20.83s)
       Cleaning assets
       Running: rake assets:clean
-----> Detecting rails configuration
###### WARNING:
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       
       To declare a Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       
       ```
       ruby "2.7.5"
       ```
       
       For more information see:
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
###### WARNING:
       Detecting rails configuration failed
       set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug
###### WARNING:
       No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
       We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 99.9M
-----> Launching...
       Released v6
       https://fathomless-river-93030.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
````

config routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'application#hello'
end
```

additional application logs from Heroku

```
    2022-02-02T19:59:41.859235+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-02-02T19:59:41.859155 #4]  INFO -- : [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] Started GET "/" for 76.9.168.21 at 2022-02-02 19:59:41 +0000
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860303+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-02-02T19:59:41.860237 #4] FATAL -- : [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4]   
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860306+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'hello' could not be found for ApplicationController):
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860307+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4]   
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860307+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:160:in `process'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860308+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860308+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860308+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860309+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860310+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860310+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860310+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860311+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860311+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860311+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860311+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860312+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860312+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860312+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:22:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860313+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860313+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860313+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860314+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860314+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860314+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860315+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860315+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860315+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860315+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860316+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] railties (6.1.4.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860316+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] railties (6.1.4.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860316+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860316+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860316+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860317+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] railties (6.1.4.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860317+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860317+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860317+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860323+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860324+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860324+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860324+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860324+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860324+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:92:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860325+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] railties (6.1.4.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860325+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] puma (5.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:249:in `call'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860325+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] puma (5.3.1) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `block in handle_request'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860325+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] puma (5.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:338:in `with_force_shutdown'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860326+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] puma (5.3.1) lib/puma/request.rb:75:in `handle_request'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860326+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] puma (5.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.860326+00:00 app[web.1]: [3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4] puma (5.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'
2022-02-02T19:59:41.853261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-river-93030.herokuapp.com request_id=3ecf5c91-ed03-4900-9fa6-1b11bfc8e4a4 fwd="76.9.168.21" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: How does your `config/routes.rb` look like?

Comment: Check this answer if it might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/26756757/14382120

Comment: @spickermann I just edited config/routes.rb in.

Comment: @VirajChheda I ran across that answer earlier. My config/routes.rb has something in it, but maybe I've got it formatted wrong in some way? I edited it into my question.